# 2 blue and 2 red balls, in a box, no replacing. Expected Value?

Tags: probability

There are 2 blue and 2 red balls, in a box. You draw all of them out without replacement. You guess the color of the ball on each draw, and you receive a dollar if you are correct. What is the dollar amount you would pay to play this game?

I just want to confirm my solution with someone since the real solution where I got this problem seems incorrect.

Expected Value on first draw: \$1/2, Second: \$2/3, Third: \$1/2(1+1/2), Fourth: \$1. Hence the expected value is: 35/12. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Do you get to see the color of a drawn ball before you have to make the next guess?

Comment: @paw88789 correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations on the third draw are off. Either you have selected two balls of the same color (probability $\frac{1}{3}$) in which case you are certain to win, or you have selected two balls of different color (probability $\frac{2}{3}$) in which case you win half of the time. We have:

First draw: $\frac{2}{4} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}$

Second draw: $\frac{2}{3} \cdot 1 = \frac{2}{3}$

Third draw: $\frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = \frac{2}{3}$

Fourth draw: $1$

Adding this all up, we arrive at $\frac{17}{6} \approx 2.83$.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not correct. For the third, what are the chances that there are 2 balls left of the same color and what are the chances that there are two left that are not the same color? They are not both equally likely, so you do not have $1/2*(1+1/2))$.